# SQL: return lector, whose ALL students passed with Excellent mark

Tags: mysql, sql

Following table: student name, student's lector name(one lector can have some students), student mark after course.

```
Stud    Lector  Mark
-----------------
Joe     Mr.A    5
Steve   Mr.A    4
Bob     Mr.B    5
Jim     Mr.D    5
Kai     Mr.C    4
Mo      Mr.A    3
Hue     Mr.B    3
Mia     Mr.D    5
```

What query will return lector(s), whose ALL students passed course excellently (got 5 mark). Just in our case - Mr.D should be returned as query result.

Comment: Hint:`NOT EXISTS(...)`

Comment: Can a given lector have the same student appear multiple times, e.g. once with a score of 1 and once with 5?  What should happen in this case?

Comment: Hi Tim. I guess, this student stops to be "excellent" man, and lector should be removed as excellent lector:). Commonly - why not? student can be mentioned some times. We can add column smth like "course"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest approach is via aggregation on the `lector`:

```
SELECT Lector
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Lector
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Mark < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it reads closely according to the actual logic you want to implement.  That is, we simply check the marks for each lector and make sure that no sub-5 marks occurred.

### Demo

Comment: I am humbled by this answer's simplicity, but it only works because you're selecting for the largest value of `mark`. It doesn't work for the general case, for example lecturers who have all `4` marks. Maybe simply changing `WHEN Mark != 5 THEN` is more flexible? Then one could use the same query for any given mark, or marks using `WHEN MARK NOT IN (...)`. Did you know that for supreme kung fu, you can simply code `HAVING SUM(mark != 5) = 0`, because in mysql true is 1 and false is 0!

Comment: @Bohemian I have asked the OP for clarification.  It is unclear how we should proceed in this case.  In any event, my query would most likely only require a small change to the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: I don't think clarification is needed. I meant if the question was "find all lecturers that *only* had marks with score `n`", of which OP's question is a specific case, the answer would be as per my previous comment, but your query would not be useful, because it assumes all marks other than `n` are less than `n`

Comment: @Bohemian A given lector has a student with both a 4 and a 5.  How would you count this?

Comment: I would not count the lecturer who had a student that scored both 4 and 5, because there exists a student that scored less than 5. Also, given the schema, it seems that lecturer/student relationship cardinality is 1. If a student could have more than 1 mark for a given lecturer, I would expect another column (perhaps date) to break the key tie

Comment: @Bohemian Hi Glen, please edit my demo link, and add data where my query would fail.  I don't see the edge case about which you are worried, which is suprising, because usually I'm the one pointing these things out.

Comment: I marked this as correct answer, as it strictly answers the question. Upper mentioned common approach(for join table itself) is cool, as well. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 2):

You have to join the table to itself; once to get the excellent marks and again to get the potentially less than excellent marks. There are a few ways to achieve this, but the best IMHO is this way:

```
select distinct a.lector
from mytable a
left join mytable b on a.lector = b.lector
    and b.mark != 5
where a.mark = 5
and b.mark is null
```

The trick here is using an outer join from excellent marks to worse marks and using `b.mark is null` to ensure there are in fact no worse marks.

Comment: I disagree.  I still don't see the edge case(s) which you are covering, and providing some sample data which highlights this would be helpful for anyone else reading this question.

Comment: @tim it's not an edge case that's missing. You answer is the edge case. Never mind, forget about it. If you haven't seen it by now after reading all my comments, more comments won't help.